# Importing JSON in Python and Removing Header

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm trying to write a simple JSON to CSV converter in Python for Kiva. The JSON file I am working with looks like this:

```
{"header":{"total":412045,"page":1,"date":"2012-04-11T06:16:43Z","page_size":500},"loans":[{"id":84,"name":"Justine","description":{"languages":["en"], REST OF DATA
```

The problem is, when I use json.load, I only get the strings "header" and "loans" in data, but not the actual information such as id, name, description, etc. How can I skip over everything until the [? I have a lot of files to process, so I can't manually delete the beginning in each one. My current code is:

```
import csv
import json

fp = csv.writer(open("test.csv","wb+"))

f = open("loans/1.json")
data = json.load(f)
f.close()

for item in data:
    fp.writerow([item["name"]] + [item["posted_date"]] + OTHER STUFF)
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
for item in data:
```

use

```
for item in data['loans']:
```

The header is stored in `data['header']` and `data` itself is a dictionary, so you'll have to key into it in order to access the data.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Thank you. I was wondering if there was a way to reference the information in header and loans within my code. Newbie Python user, so the dictionaries still confuse me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a dictionary, so `for item in data` iterates the *keys*.

You probably want `for loan in data['loans']:`

Comment: Ah, okay. So if I wanted to iterate through all the data in all the keys, I would nest a loop like

    for keys in data
       for item in data[keys]
          DO STUFF

Comment: You can do that, but in python if you are iterating keys+values you usually just iterate both at the same time instead of using another for-loop: `for key,value in data.items(): DO STUFF`